# bad operand types for binary operator "&" java

Tags: java, binary, operand

The error shows this line

```
 if ((a[0] & 1 == 0) && (a[1] & 1== 0) && (a[2] & 1== 0)){
```

This is the whole code:

```
public class Ex4 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  int [] a = new int [3];
  if(args.length == 3)
  {
      try{
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        }
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){
            System.out.println("Wrong Argument");
       }
      if ((a[0] & 1 == 0) && (a[1] & 1== 0) && (a[2] & 1== 0)){
        System.out.println("yes");
      }
    else {
        System.out.println("no");
    }
  }
  else{
      System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
}
```

I've fixed the code:

```
if ((a[0] & 1) == 0 && (a[1] & 1) == 0 && (a[2] & 1) == 0){
```

Was an issue with the brackets, updated for anyone in the future.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`==` has higher precedence than `&`. You might want to wrap your operations in `()` to specify how you want your operands to bind to the operators.

```
((a[0] & 1) == 0)
```

Similarly for all parts of the `if` condition.

Answer (score 3):

Because `&` has a *lesser* priority than `==`.

Your code is equivalent to `a[0] & (1 == 0)`, and unless `a[0]` is a boolean this won't compile...

You need to:

```
(a[0] & 1) == 0
```

etc etc.

(yes, Java does hava a boolean `&` operator -- a non shortcut logical and)

Comment: What does mean `a non shortcut logical and`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more precise, using parentheses, otherwise Java will not use the order of operands that you want it to use.

```
if ((a[0] & 1 == 0) && (a[1] & 1== 0) && (a[2] & 1== 0)){
```

Becomes

```
if (((a[0] & 1) == 0) && ((a[1] & 1) == 0) && ((a[2] & 1) == 0)){
```